# Find diseases from users suffering for a specific disease

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, subquery

EDITED:

I trying to get all other DISEASES from users suffering for disease A.

OLD QUESTION (WRONG):

I trying to get users suffering from some disease also suffer for other diseases:

```
class User
  has_many :treatments
end

class Disease
  has_many :treatments
end

class Treatment
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :disease
end
```

I have some working code:

Get all users ids who suffer for specific disease:

```
user_ids = Treatment.joins(:user).where(disease_id: 250).pluck(:user_id)
```

Get all diseases based on users ids

```
Disease.where("id != 250").where(id: Treatment.select("DISTINCT disease_id").where(user_id: user_ids))
```

Is there simpler way? Maybe one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED:
If you want to use one query, you could use this one:

```
select distinct d1.id from diseases as d1 
  JOIN treatments as t1 on d1.id=t1.disease_id 
  where exists (
    select t2.id from treatments as t2 
      where t2.disease_id = 250 AND t2.user_id=t1.user_id
  ) AND d1.id <> 250;
```

Comment: Sorry, I asked the wrong question ;/ It should be: I looking for Diseases not for users. So first I looking for all users suffering for disease A and then I need list of other diseases from this users.

Comment: There are X users who has disease_id 250 and disease from result. For example: There are 10 users who has got disease 250 and disease 500. How can I order result (in query above) by users count? This is query which counts users who has two specific diseases http://pastie.org/private/xdcgh3ocmlwrmocnnwtzgq but I don't know hot to connect..